# Is there a way to automatically fold specific XML/HTML/SVG tags in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It doesn't matter if its an extension or a change in config, Ex. SVGs are sometimes a pain to work with.

Comment: For svg's can you give an example of an svg you do want to fold vs. an svg you do not want to fold.  Or do you want to fold all svg's?

Answer (score 0):

The answer (at least for vanilla VS Code with no extensions) is: at the time of this writing, no.

Google "`vscode auto fold specific html tag`", and you'll find [Automatic folding/collapsing of specified HTML tags (ie. ) on file load
#84844](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84844) (pretty much an exact match of what you're looking for), which is closed in favour of the more general [[folding] configure initial collapse state #40338](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40338) issue ticket, which is still open and not yet. To be honest, I'm not sure if that was a good closure, since the target issue seems to be less related. In any case, you can give that issue a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress. <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

---

As for solutions for non-vanilla-VS-Code, you could take a look at the [`=moalamri.inline-fold`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moalamri.inline-fold) extension <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>. [Their readme even shows how to use it for SVG](https://github.com/moalamri/vscode-inline-fold#svg):

```json
"inlineFold.regex":  "<svg(\\s*.*?\\s*)<\/svg>",
"inlineFold.regexFlags": "gs",
"inlineFold.regexGroup": 1,
```

If you only want it to apply for certain file types, then wrap the setting in a language block. Ex.

```json
"[html]": {
  "inlineFold.regex":  "<svg(\\s*.*?\\s*)<\/svg>",
  "inlineFold.regexFlags": "gs",
  "inlineFold.regexGroup": 1
}
```